# How to change mysql column type from float to double and save values as it is?

Tags: mysql, sql, migration

When I try to change data type from float to double all decimal values are changed too.
For example 0.3 becomes 0.30000001192092896. How to avoid this?
I just use

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` MODIFY `weight` double;
```

Comment: Your value isn't really 0.3 to begin with.  If you want 0.3 (or 0.300000), then use a decimal data type.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of "binary fractions do not directly match to decimals"and "Never compare floats for equality" ...

After the ALTER you can try:

```
UPDATE table1 set weight = ROUND(weight, 7);
```

(or maybe try 6 instead of 7) to get rid of the extra conversion noise ...

Comment: 'ang on a minute here!  The problem with floating point (either `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`) is that it doesn't always translate cleanly to a decimal representation. Your suggestion here alters the data in the table, but it still has to be translated to decimal to be displayed. The application's numerical integrity will be improved by **not** doing what you suggest, but rather formatting the results only before displaying them, and immediately before showing them to an end user who doesn't understand floating point.